# have container size equal image size

Tags: css

How can I get my container equal the size of my image. I have the image scale with the window and I have it sit inside a container because it a image slider.

**CSS**

```
#full_image { 
 overflow:hidden;
 position:absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
 opacity: 0;
}

#full_image  ul {
 display: -moz-inline-stack;
}

#full_image ul li img{
 width:100%;
 max-width:100%;  
 overflow: hidden;    
 display: inline-block;  
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="full_image"> 
    <ul>
       <li>
           <img src="'+img+'"/>
       </li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: I'm not sure you need `width` and `max-width`

Comment: yes that's what allowing my image to scale with the window size

Comment: see jsfiddle in answer below both are not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yasP2/).  I added some extra CSS to show the borders.

1. You notice you can change the width of the `#full_image` and the image scales (width does not need to be specified for it to fill the space it's there as an example).
2. You only need max-width to allow it to scale.
3. I noticed you have `opacity` at 0, I removed that so you could see the image.